# Buttons not highlighting on touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, highlighting

Im new to IOS development. I have a view with two buttons "create" and "cancel" but they are no highlighting. They appear on top of a pdf that allow longpress  for copy/cup/paste). Actually "create" highlights really fast, but cancel does not change state at all. Any idea what might be causing this.

```
-(IBAction)create:(id)sender{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name your object" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save",nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];

}

-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kExitAnnotationView object:nil ];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I you "create" action is mapped on the TouchDown you wont be able to see the Highlighted state of you button

Answer (score 0):

In your cancel method you are removing the superview...Actually your cancel button is highlighting but You are not able to see that..If you want to see that you can perform the actions inside your cancel method a bit later using timer with a 1 second or less delay.
Same thing you can do in create method. Hope it will work...:)